# ¿Como anidar un scroll dentro de un widget texto que esta adentro de un widget card?

Tags: app, flutter, dart

espero que esten bien, tengo la siguiente duda:

1) ¿cual es la manera correcta de crear un Widget card y que el contenido interno del mismo sea scrolleable (que se pueda subir y bajar) sin mover el card?

Yo intente hacerlo con la siguiente estructura pero se me desaparece el texto dentro del card y no estoy muy seguro de como avanzar.

```
Widget _viewCardTerminosCondiciones(){
return ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500.0),
  child:Card(
  elevation: 9.0,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,right: 20.0,bottom: 20.0),
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
        'Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset".',
        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
      ),
        ], 
      ),
    ),
  )
);}
```

Intente usar un SingleChildScrollView pero no toma el scroll se queda fijo y con el ListView desaparece el texto interior... Disculpen si la pregunta es muy tonta, muchas gracias de antemano y que tengan buen dia.

Comment: He probado tu código y va bien, quizas el problema que tengas es como está posicionado ese widget dentro del parent y otros widgets que tengas, agrega más información sobre tu pantalla actual , como se ve y como quieres que se vea, y si puedes agregar más código sería genial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final me ayudaron desde otro lado y esta es la respuesta:

```
Widget _viewCardTerminosCondiciones(context){
return ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400.0),
  child:Card(
  elevation: 9.0,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0,right: 20.0,bottom: 20.0),
    child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
      height: 300,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: RichText(
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'texto largo aqui',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),
  )
);}
```